# Is there a lightweight MTA for Ubuntu 9.10 Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, email-server

I'm writing a Perl script to run as a cron job, and I want to email results & errors to a local account on the laptop.  I'd like something that can talk SMTP (do any MTAs *not* adhere to SMTP?).  I use Thunderbird 3, so I'll also need a POP/IMAP server (unless T-Bird can read straight from an mbox file; I'll have to check into that).  No need for spam controls as I'll lock it down real tight, only accepting mail originating from the laptop itself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install [Postfix](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/postfix), configure it for the [local network](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#local_network) and make it [listen only to the loopback-interface](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces).

If you have an external mailbox ready and only want to send emails to it, you could probably just install [ssmtp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/ssmtp) and be happy.

Answer (score 2):

there's [ssmtp](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/SSMTP), right there in the standard repositories

Comment: I want to deliver mail locally, so I think sSMTP is out.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Nullmailer](http://bit.ly/QOZnqe). I think it is the best lightweight mail transfer agent for ubuntu and other Linux. Hopefully that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird's standard mail format is mbox, you could try [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) for an MTA.

Comment: IMHO Apache James is not quite what you'd call "lightweight". ;)

Comment: Apache James does not look lightweight :)  Thanks for the T-bird info, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider [courier](http://www.courier-mta.org/), which provides a complete email suite (SMTP, IMAP, and much more)

Answer (score -1):

consider qmail with courier-imap 
will turn it into a full scale smtp but can easily be locked down to local network if required. While most people think it complex it is actually fairly simple and lightweight in terms of resource utilization .... while there is no install I know of for ubuntu there is a scripted install for debian available here  http://itsjustit.co.uk/chalfontcomputers/qmailscript/netqmail-djb.tar.gz
The script installs with Maildir format so simply using the courier-imap with qmail will allow the laptop to connect as easily as to any pop or imap server ... you will have a full blown smtp that is very robust.

Comment: The OP was pretty clear that he needs this to be simple, and he's right. It's for accepting mail on localhost; a "full blown" system is too complex for these requirements.